# Install pdftk-1.44 on ubuntu 16

Tags: pdftk

We have installed Ubuntu 16.04 and apt-get install pdftk install the release 2.02

But I need to install the pdftk-1.44 for an application dependency related.

Any help in this matter would be highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: This one https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/mipsel/pdftk/download?

Answer (score 0):

The package (.deb) *pdftk 1.44* can be found [at packages.debian](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/mipsel/pdftk/download). As well as many other packages and different versions of them.